# Swipe function to delete a table row in Swift is not animating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app using Swift 3, I want to allow the user to swipe a row in a `UITableView` to delete it from the table. [This guide](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/delete-rows-table-view-ios8-swift) makes it look pretty simple, and I've implemented with no XCode errors.

As shown in the last method, the user should be able to swipe, and the selected row will be removed. After running in simulator, nothing seems to happen, and there is no console output.

I am new to Swift -- is there a better way to approach this? As a note, `thedownloads` is the data source that contains the array stored in each table cell. I've included that code as an FYI.

```
var thedownloads = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get the document directory url
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    do {
        // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

        // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
        let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }
        //print("mp3 urls:",mp3Files)
        let mp3FileNames = mp3Files.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
        //print("mp3 list:", mp3FileNames)

        thedownloads = mp3FileNames

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "showcell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = thedownloads[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// this is where I try to run the delete animation 

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        thedownloads.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using beginUpdates() and endUpdates()

Comment: Issue should be  with this line i`ndexPath as IndexPath`  Looks like your method is  `commitEditingStyle` has some issues . Observe there is NSIndexpath while other delegate has IndexPath.

Comment: @SuganyaMarlin For single row updation you don't need  `beginUpdates() and endUpdates()`

Comment: You should copy paste method from delegate protocol of UITableViewDelegate you should not write it by your self .

Comment: What does “nothing seems to happen” mean? What does the user do, how does the app respond, and what were you hoping for?

Comment: Hey, this was resolved below -- I wasn't overriding due to the old syntax issue, so the animation would not show. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate your error and it depends on these things:

1: You´re not overriding `commitEditingStyle`

2: You´re using and old syntax of `commitEditingStyle`

Update you´re `commit EditingStyle` function to this and it will work for you:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        thedownloads.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad to help.